# Latex command for a specic picture of aligned equations

Tags: syntax

I want to type the following in latex
[image]

In principal I want to have a long equation in the beginning line. Then I want to have short equations properly centered (with each other and also with the long equation) like the picture. Note that the 'imply' symbol is also properly aligned. Please help me to write a latex code which should produce the same picture. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you consider the `align` or `aligned` environments? Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and tell us where exactly you're having problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that? (loading Fourier is here only because I prefer it to Computer Modern, and you can remove it, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  x_5 = i 5 + j(p + q + \gamma) + k(l+ m)\\
  \begin{aligned}
    i = 1, j = 1 & \implies x_5 = \beta \\
    i = 2, j = 3 & \implies x_5 = q \\
    i = 2, j = 1 & \implies x_5 = m
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should point out that `\usepackage{fourier}` is not necessary for the example. I believe it's better to avoid font packages, so the answer is as generic as possible.

Comment: OK I'll do that.

Comment: Yes it works but if I want to number the beginning long line and refer to it in a later part of my text what command should I use?

Comment: You can use `gather` instead of `gather*`,  and `\notag` with the `aligned` block if you don't need to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you want,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
$x_5 = i5 + j(p+q+r) + k (l+m)$   

\begin{tabular}{ll}
$i=1,$   $j=1$   $\Rightarrow$  $x_5 = \beta$  \\ 
$i=2,$   $j=3$   $\Rightarrow$  $x_5 = q$  \\
$i=2,$   $j=1$   $\Rightarrow$  $x_5 = m$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}   


\end{document}
```

Just try this.